# Payment systems with paypal with pre authorisation and incremental use of credit

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I am developing a commerce app with php/mysql. My boss wants this:

- user can buy "ad credits" on our website and he wants this to be a paypal pre authorisation
- then the user can use ad bundles with various costs
- this costs are taken from the ad credits and he wants this to be the actual decrement of user credits in paypal

Example: John buys an ad credits pack of 30$. He pre authorises this trasaction with his paypal account. Then he buys two banner spaces for the cost of 10$. So 10$ are taken from his paypal.

Is this possible? Paypal APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could handle this.

1) You could use [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec) to setup a billing agreement with the buyer and then use [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) to process future payments using that billing agreement.

You can do the same thing with Payments Pro, too.  In your original request you would just run an Authorization of 1.00 and then immediately void that authorization.  You could then use that transaction ID you get back from the authorization to process future payments with DoReferenceTransaction.

2) You could setup a Preapproval Profile with the buyer using the [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) API.  You would then use the [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) API to process payments in the future using the preapproval key you got back from that Preapproval API.  This is all explained in detail in the [Adaptive Payments documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).